# Select Duplicate Entries from a database table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, self-join

I have a two columns in a table say columnA and columnB. I want to select duplicate entries for columnA where columnB=xx or columnB=yy.
For Example

```
columnA columnB
12      abc
12      pqr
11      abc
10      pqr
9       xyz
```

for above table I want to get 12 as a result. which is common for columnB=abc or columnB=pqr.

Please help me to build a sql query. I tried with count(*) but coudn't get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c66e2/5/0):

```
SELECT a.columnA
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN MyTable b ON a.columnA = b.columnA 
WHERE a.columnB = 'abc'
AND b.columnB = 'pqr';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columnA, count(columnA) 
FROM tableName 
GROUP BY columnA
HAVING count(columnA)>1
```

this will at least give you a list of all duplicated entries, followed by the count of dupes.

Comment: Yes, this gave me all the duplicate entries. but my need is to find duplicate entries for two columnB entries. Thanks for the try.